# Apache trailing slash role while posting HTML form

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, post

Probably duplicate, but I haven't seen response that works for me.

I am trying to figure out how to handle action URL at POST form properly with .htaccess

This does not pass POST data through:

```
<html>
<form action="http://somesite.net/subdir" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name= "myval" value="12345">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Result an empty POST array:

```
POSTarray(0) { }
```

However this works just fine:

```
<form action="http://somesite.net/subdir/" method="post">
```

Critical thing is the last  trailing slash which if not given, then post are lost.

I have in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^subdir$ subdir/ [R=301,L]
```

Can the reason be be that RewriteBase causes POST data lost and how to avoid that?

Comment: RewriteBase defines a base url for your relative rewrite target and it has nothing to do with the form. Your rewriteRule performs an external redirection from **/dir** to **/dir/** that is why the post data is getting lost. Remove the Rule completly and retest.

Comment: OK, I now left only RewriteBase / in mod_rewrite module and no changes. POST is still lost

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: did cleared the cache, still POST is lost when removing last slash from the  action URL